# Is pyspark compatible with multiple spark server versions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, multiple-versions

I have an environment with two spark servers of different versions: spark 3.3.2 and spark 3.4.1

I need to use `pyspark` from a single python session to connect to the two instances above - of spark servers of different versions
Is that possible?
when i tried to connect pyspark 3.4.1 to the spark 3.3.2 server or pyspark 3.3.2 to a 3.4.1 spark server i get weird Java errors that don't say anything about versions mismatch.

Which `pyspark` version should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommended you to use the corresponding version of `PySpark` for each Spark server. `PySpark` is tightly integrated with the Spark version it is built for, and using a different version may result in compatibility issues and unexpected errors that you may not notice the root cause from error codes.